# Wordnet taxonomy construction

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I'd like to build a minimum encompassing taxonomic tree for a given set of wordnet synsets. For a set of 2 synsets the tree would be one where they are both children nodes of their lowest common hypernym.

For the following set:

```
[{'name': 'tench.n.01'},
 {'name': 'goldfish.n.01'},
 {'name': 'great_white_shark.n.01'},
 {'name': 'tiger_shark.n.01'},
 {'name': 'hammerhead.n.03'}]
```

The required result is:

```
{'name': 'fish.n.01',
 'children': [{'name': 'cyprinid.n.01',
   'children': [{'name': 'tench.n.01'}, {'name': 'goldfish.n.01'}]},
  {'name': 'shark.n.01',
   'children': [{'name': 'tiger_shark.n.01'},
    {'name': 'great_white_shark.n.01'},
    {'name': 'hammerhead.n.03'}]}]}
```

I had some success with relatively small sets. Once I try larger sets things start to break down.

E.g. for a 30 long set I got a tree that can be visualized as follows:

[image]

One can see for example that the great gray owl is not classified under bird.

## Code example

Below I give a reproducible example in python of what I got so far:

### Define tree building function

```
# import nltk
# nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd
def synset_tree(synsets):
    # find similarities between all leaf nodes
    synsets_sim = []
    for i,j in combinations(range(len(synsets)),2):
        synsets_sim.append(pd.DataFrame({'syn1':[synsets[i]["name"]], 'syn2':[synsets[j]["name"]], 
        'sim':[wn.synset(synsets[i]["name"]).path_similarity(wn.synset(synsets[j]["name"]))]}))
    synsets_sim = pd.concat(synsets_sim, axis=0)

    while len(synsets)>1:
        synsets_sim = synsets_sim.sort_values('sim', ascending=False)
        
        # Find common ancestor of 2 closest leaf nodes
        common_hype = wn.synset(synsets_sim.syn1.iloc[0]).lowest_common_hypernyms(wn.synset(synsets_sim.syn2.iloc[0]))[0].name()
        # extract 2 leaf nodes
        syn_dict1 = list(filter(lambda x: x["name"] == synsets_sim.syn1.iloc[0], synsets))[0]
        syn_dict2 = list(filter(lambda x: x["name"] == synsets_sim.syn2.iloc[0], synsets))[0]
        # remove lead nodes from leaf node list
        synsets = [syn_dict for syn_dict in synsets if syn_dict not in [syn_dict1, syn_dict2]]
        
        # The common hypernym will replace the 2 leaf nodes. Calculate it's similarity to all remaining leaf nodes. 
        new_sim = []
        for i in range(len(synsets)):
            new_sim.append(pd.DataFrame({'syn1':[synsets[i]["name"]], 'syn2':[common_hype], 
            'sim':[wn.synset(synsets[i]["name"]).path_similarity(wn.synset(common_hype))]}))
        if len(new_sim) > 0:
            new_sim = pd.concat(new_sim, axis=0)
            new_sim = new_sim[new_sim.sim<1]
            synsets_sim = pd.concat([synsets_sim, new_sim],axis=0)

        # Add children of the nodes being removed to the common hypernym
        if common_hype == syn_dict1["name"]:
            if syn_dict1.get("children"):
                common_hype = {"name":common_hype, "children":[syn_dict2] + syn_dict1.get("children")}
            else:
                common_hype = {"name":common_hype, "children":[syn_dict2]}
            synsets_sim = synsets_sim[~((synsets_sim.syn1 == syn_dict2["name"]) | (synsets_sim.syn2 == syn_dict2["name"]))]
        elif common_hype == syn_dict2["name"]:
            if syn_dict2.get("children"):
                common_hype = {"name":common_hype, "children":[syn_dict1] + syn_dict2.get("children")}
            else:
                common_hype = {"name":common_hype, "children":[syn_dict1]}
            synsets_sim = synsets_sim[~((synsets_sim.syn1 == syn_dict1["name"]) | (synsets_sim.syn2 == syn_dict1["name"]))]
        elif common_hype in [x["name"] for x in synsets]:
            for i in range(len(synsets)):
                if common_hype == synsets[i]["name"]:
                    if synsets[i]["children"]:
                        synsets[i]["children"] = synsets[i]["children"] + [syn_dict1, syn_dict2]
                    else:
                        synsets[i]["children"] = [syn_dict1, syn_dict2]
        else:
            common_hype = {"name":common_hype, "children":[syn_dict1, syn_dict2]}
            synsets_sim = synsets_sim[~((synsets_sim.syn1 == syn_dict1["name"]) | (synsets_sim.syn2 == syn_dict1["name"]))]
            synsets_sim = synsets_sim[~((synsets_sim.syn1 == syn_dict2["name"]) | (synsets_sim.syn2 == syn_dict2["name"]))]
 

        synsets.append(common_hype)
        

    return synsets[0]
```

### Input set that works

```
synsets = [{'name': 'tench.n.01'},
 {'name': 'goldfish.n.01'},
 {'name': 'great_white_shark.n.01'},
 {'name': 'tiger_shark.n.01'},
 {'name': 'hammerhead.n.03'},
 {'name': 'electric_ray.n.01'},
 {'name': 'stingray.n.01'},
 {'name': 'cock.n.05'},
 {'name': 'hen.n.02'},
 {'name': 'ostrich.n.02'},
 {'name': 'brambling.n.01'},
 {'name': 'goldfinch.n.02'},
 {'name': 'house_finch.n.01'},
 {'name': 'junco.n.01'},
 {'name': 'indigo_bunting.n.01'},
 {'name': 'robin.n.02'},
 {'name': 'bulbul.n.01'},
 {'name': 'jay.n.02'},
 {'name': 'magpie.n.01'},
 {'name': 'chickadee.n.01'},
 {'name': 'water_ouzel.n.01'},
 {'name': 'kite.n.04'},
 {'name': 'bald_eagle.n.01'},
 {'name': 'vulture.n.01'},
 {'name': 'great_grey_owl.n.01'},
 {'name': 'european_fire_salamander.n.01'},
 {'name': 'common_newt.n.01'},
 {'name': 'eft.n.01'},
 {'name': 'spotted_salamander.n.01'},
 {'name': 'axolotl.n.01'}]

wow = synset_tree(synsets[:5])
wow
```

```
{'name': 'fish.n.01',
 'children': [{'name': 'cyprinid.n.01',
   'children': [{'name': 'tench.n.01'}, {'name': 'goldfish.n.01'}]},
  {'name': 'shark.n.01',
   'children': [{'name': 'tiger_shark.n.01'},
    {'name': 'great_white_shark.n.01'},
    {'name': 'hammerhead.n.03'}]}]}
```

### Input set that fails

```
wow = synset_tree(synsets) # this gives the tree which produces the above image
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something not stable/symmetrical about your code, but (unhelpfully) I haven't spotted it yet. Did you develop this code yourself, or get it from somewhere? It'd be helpful if it had more comments or helper functions, as it is a bit complicated currently.

If you comment out cock and hen (which both have "bird" as their immediate hypernym), then you get generally correct results: the great grey owl is under birds of prey with the others.

And if you instead move cock and hen to the end of the list you get different (still wrong) groupings. Not a good sign when order of the data matters. So it seems something to do with dealing with data where its immediate hypernym is what you are trying to group under?

Comment: I did develop this entirety by myself. Obviously, I agree there's something wrong with the code. Will add some comments soon. Thx